# Google Analytics Reporting Api v4 Report Request response has row count but empty rows element

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have 980+ viewids I'm running report requests for on a daily basis. They are being loaded into a rs db.

I have the report requests do an initial 3 month backfill run for all of the ids.

When checking over the data we noticed that some of the ids seemed to not have had the backfill run for them. I looked over the logs and wasn't receiving any kind of error from the api.

I started running single report requests for individual viewids and were getting back row values in the response.

I added more logging to our application that's making the requests because I thought I maybe just wasn't catching the error.

For the first 850 or so I get back what is expected. Data for the past 3 months if there is any.

The last 100+ ids I have been getting responses for viewids that have a row count, maximums, minimums and totals that are not 0 and an empty rows element. And that's where I'm stuck at now. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature of the api. Couldn't find any previous mention of any similar issue anywhere.

Some Notes:

We have 12 report requests running simultaneously on one server daily. In the Api console we are seeing about 12,000 requests a day go out. It is a node application that is making the requests. We have not noticed this happening when doing our daily report requests for all the viewids, We aren't hitting the daily limit of 50,000 requests, we do have exponential back off implemented, and we are retrying when we hit the rate limiting errors.

Example of one of our report requests:

```
`{
"reportRequests": [
{
"dateRanges": [
{
  "startDate": "2017-06-01",
   "endDate" : "2017-09-01"
}
],
"metrics": [
  {"expression": "ga:entrances"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:goalAbandonsAll"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:users"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:sessions"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:bounces"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:goalStartsAll"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:sessionDuration"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:goalValueAll"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:pageviews"}, 
  {"expression": "ga:timeOnPage"}
],
"pageSize": 10000, 
"includeEmptyRows": true, 
"dimensions": [
  {"name": "ga:adwordsCreativeID"},
  {"name": "ga:adSlot"},
  {"name": "ga:adTargetingType"},
  {"name": "ga:adDistributionNetwork"},
  {"name": "ga:adKeywordMatchType"},
  {"name": "ga:hour"},
  {"name": "ga:date"}
],
"samplingLevel": "LARGE",
"viewId": "123456789"
}
]
}`
```

Weird response we see:

```
`{
"columnHeader":{
"dimensions":[
"ga:adwordsCreativeID",
"ga:adSlot",
"ga:adTargetingType",
"ga:adDistributionNetwork",
"ga:adKeywordMatchType",
"ga:hour",
"ga:date"
],
"metricHeader":{
"metricHeaderEntries":[
{"name":"ga:entrances","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:goalAbandonsAll","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:users","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:sessions","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:bounces","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:goalStartsAll","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:sessionDuration","type":"TIME"},{"name":"ga:goalValueAll","type":"CURRENCY"},{"name":"ga:pageviews","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:timeOnPage","type":"TIME"}
]
}},
"data":{
"totals":[
{"values":["1235","0","1245","1235","1091","0","63517.0","0.0","1450","63515.0"]}
],
"rowCount":602,
"minimums":[
{"values":["0","0","1","0","0","0","0.0","0.0","1","0.0"]}
],
"maximums":[
{"values":["10","0","10","10","8","0","4920.0","0.0","16","4909.0"]}
],
"rows":[]}`
```

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one this is happening to, but not glad it's happening. Would love to hear a Google dev shed some light on what might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any more information about this issue? It seems that if you get an "empty" report (only containing min/max/totals) as a response from Google Analytics, sending a new request will solve the issue.
Checking for report['data]['rows'] is one way to identify if a report is "empty" or not.

```
response = [...]
while self.is_response_empty(response):
    response = [...]

def is_response_empty(self, response):
    for report in response.get('reports', []):
        try:
            report['data']['rows']
            return False
        except:
            return True
```